# Establishing I/O Patterns for an Application

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, performance, profiling

Are there any system tools that allow you to profile an application's usage of storage? Basically, I'm looking for information on determining whether there are more large sequential reads, tiny sequential read, random writes with backtracks, etc.

Comment: Even if it's just profiling that's system-wide that would work too, the application will be pretty much the only one using the block devicein question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the answer. Kind of obvious and I'm a little ashamed I didn't think of it before. But here it goes: Bascially blktrace/blkparse are the commands we're looking for. [This](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2009/10/block-io-layer-tracing-using-blktrace.html) is the general idea I'm basing it off of, but I can pipe the output of blktrace to blkparse then save blkparse's output to a file. Once the profiling is done I can look at the activity logs at the top, filtering for the pids I'm interested in with awk. Saving all the output to a file is so I can use awk to filter for PID's but I can also use it's summary section at the end.

Basically the regular output of blkparse's activity log are lines like this:

```
  8,0    3      523    55.007588437 22191  M  WS 548087528 + 8 [qemu-kvm]
```

"22191" is the PID and "M" means that it was back merged with a request already issued to the device, "WS" means it was a synchronous write starting at sector 548087528 and going for eight more sectors. More information about blktrace can be found in [their users manual](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~aaronc/iosched/doc/blktrace.html).

Figured that I would post this for posterity.